# XPages Extension Library cannot be found

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I'm getting the error below when I run my application:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: The application /test/Test.nsf requires com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library
```

The extension library cannot be found, but the library was installed by replicating the updatesite.nsf from the main server to the current server throwing this error.

When I issue the command below:

```
tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib
```

The log show that the library is ACTIVE, but does not show that it has been INSTALLED.

[image]

Since the library is already on the server, how can I install it?

Your support will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.ibm.xsp.extlib.relational.library` is not part of the core 9.0.1 Extension Library. It was only incorporated into the core *OpenNTF* Extension Library in 9.0.1_v00_10. It was not incorporated into core *IBM* Extension Library until Feature Pack 8. You will see that nothing starting `com.ibm.xsp.extlib` is referenced in your screenshot of the server console, and version 9.0.1_v00_00 which shows you only have 9.0.1 base Extension Library installed. There are three options:

- Install ExtLibX component from the OpenNTF Extension Library. You will still be using the base 9.0.1 version for all other controls.
- Upgrade the version of the Extension Library to a more recent version, e.g. 9.0.1_v00_17. This will override the base 9.0.1 version of all Extension Library controls.
- Upgrade to 9.0.1 Feature Pack 8.

Note that if you use ExtLibX, SSJS code or XPages components will continue to work when you subsequently upgrade ExtLib (or Domino to FP8+). However, to avoid name collisions, the Java class names will change. If you use custom Java code, you will need to edit and update the classes to the new Java package names when upgrading in the future.

Comment: I have disabled all the old extension libraries and enabled the latest one and all seems to work now. Thanks.